# for loop to read same name with different number

Tags: r, for-loop

I have several data frames named kpi1,kpi2,kpi3,... .I want to create one data frame that includes some rows of each of these data frames (that contain certain values). I have the code to extract what I want from each of them, but I would like to write a loop to select each of these data frames at each iteration, perform the extraction, and go to the next file. So in the first iteration I can do stuff with kpi1, second iteration with kpi2, and so on.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mget` to collect them into a list, then use `lapply` or `sapply` to process each one.

Or you can use `get` in the loop.  Use either `sprintf` or `paste0` to create the list of names.

```
out1 <- lapply( mget( sprintf( 'kpi%d', 1:25 ) ), function(df) df[1:3, ] )
out2 <- do.call(rbind, out1)
```

In general it is better to keep multiple data frames that you will be iterating over like this in a single list rather than have each one in its own data frame in the global environment.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I tried using lapply as you suggested, but the function I want to use, itself is changing in each iteration, i.e. I want to subset kpi1, add it to out1, subset kpi2, add it, till the end. Can you guide me through this?